WSO2 API Manager not Enforcing Rate Limiting with Subscription and Resource Configuration
I'm facing an issue with WSO2 API Manager regarding rate limiting. I have configured rate limiting through subscriptions and resources but it doesn't seem to be enforced as expected.
I have set up rate limiting in WSO2 API Manager where a particular subscription is allowed to access a specific resource endpoint only 10 times per minute.
However, when I exceed this limit by making more than 10 requests within a minute, instead of receiving a throttled-out message, I still receive successful responses.
Here's an overview of the policies setup using the Admin Portal:
Subscription Level:

Rate Limiting Policy: 10 requests per minute
In the Publisher Portal under Resources rate limiting is set on API level:
Rate Limiting Policy: 10 requests per minute
I've checked the configuration multiple times to ensure that I haven't missed any steps. I've also verified that the API Gateway components are properly configured.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

At some point, has your requests throttled out?

It did not @chashikajw

Are you trying this out in a all-in-one setup or distributed setup? if it is a distributed setup, then there could be an issue with setting up the environment. Refer distributed deployment docs .
Can you check whether out-of-the box throttling tiers work in this setup? for example, you could try creating app with existing 10 request per min Application level tier and try to see whether any of the throttling works first. If it works then we could assume there is no issue in the deployment
Finally can you check whether you have enabled Stop On Quota Reach in your subscription level policy. If this is not enabled, requests are not  blocked after throttled out.

